# disabling secure boot - no OS works, F2 or F10 don't work

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Do you know if forcibly formatting all of the partitions of a windows-native computer might kill the boot-secure ?

Long story short: I am trying to make my computer a dual-boot windows-linux, but I have issues with the boot secure. Big issues.

Long story long: I got a windows7 computer two-three years ago, and when trying to dual-boot it with ubuntu I accidentally erased windows. Now I really need it, so I tried to reinstall windows, but it wouldn't start on my usb flash drive, and I probably accidentally turned the boot secure on again when I was messing with the boot order. It was kind of ok with ubuntu (it asked for a weird numbers password on startup but it worked), but I thought I'd install debian instead, and so I overwrote ubuntu (having saved my data beforehand).

Now I have Debian and HDD0, which might be an empty partition. If I try to start it normally it tells me it doesn't have the permissions to start (because of secureboot), the F2 and F10 keys I used before to access the windows boot menu don't work anymore, and if I try to boot it on my multisystem usb drive, the ubuntu liveCD doesn't have the permissions either, the debian install one work for installing, but not for actually using it, the windows one tells me "can't find command 'drivemap' " and "invalid EFI filepath" (which it seems you need a working os to fix, according to that: http://www.simplehelp.net/2013/07/10/how-to-fix-the-cant-find-command-drivemap-error-after-installing-ubuntu/ ) and all the rest complain about permissions.

It might solve it if I completely overwrite all partitions, including the EFI one (which I probably haven't changed yet), but I'd rather not do it if either you know it'll end up in a disaster, or there is another way. After all, "it can't get any worse now, I can try whatever I want" has already been proven wrong a few times in the past day.

Thanks!

(I know this isn't an Ubuntu-specific question, but it's not really a Debian-specific question either, and I only very rarely, if ever, saw a thread about Debian and dual-boot, while there are lots with Ubuntu. And let's get real, the Windows people won't know anything about it)

Comment: When you 'disable secure boot' it does NOT actually do so, until it warns you to accept this change (and enter short code) on next startup. *So check if you have secure boot enabled. Also try resetting BIOS to defaults, and then check settings.*

Comment: I did disable it at the beginning, I think, but then I went back to the usine settings in case I had messed something there and I probably forgot to turn it back off. How do I check if secure boot is enabled? I tried every Fnumber key, and I remember the BIOS menu popped up, when it worked, on F2 or F10, which now doesn't do anything.

Comment: You need to identify the brand/model of computer, in case it is different. *Try re-starting with <Esc> pressed. This should prompt you with an options menu, including (usually) <F10> for BIOS settings.*

Comment: Thanks! I managed to disable secure boot with a windows recovery usb drive, but now on boot it shows me "GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.3" and tells me "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported", and a prompt "grub> ". But multisystem looks like it'll work, so I think I'll try to install a linux distribution and see from there.

Answer (score 1):

Secure boot is implemented in the BIOS. Reformatting won't remove it. You need to go into the BIOS settings and find the option to disable it.